# ImportError: libgeos-3.6.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, matplotlib-basemap

I installed mpl_toolkits.basemap yet it is still not working. In ipython I am trying:

```
In [1]: from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d9467465a3b6> in <module>()
----> 1 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py in <module>()
     37 import numpy as np
     38 import numpy.ma as ma
---> 39 import _geoslib
     40 import functools
     41 

ImportError: libgeos-3.6.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Still not working. Help.

Comment: Have you installed it from source?  It looks like you need to link the GEOS library properly for it to work.  See step (2) in the readme: [Matplotlib README](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Yes I did install from source code I have no idea what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when trying to install PostGIS. Installing the following fixed the error for me

```
sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a similar error. I fixed it finding the location of the library. In my case the location was different that where all my libs where, so I moved it to the correct folder and it worked.